# Script is not showing any error but still not able to send email via python

Tags: python, dataframe, win32com

i am simply trying to send an email to someone whatever is stored in dataframe and when i run the script it ends with process finished with exit code 0 but i see nothing in my sent items.Earlier it was working fine not sure what has gotten into it.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import datetime
from plyer import notification
import win32com.client as win32



today = datetime.date.today()


df = pd.read_sql(sql = query, con = engine)


if df.shape[0] == 0:
    print('No result!!!')

else:
     olApp = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
     #olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
     mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
     Body ='''\
     <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>
            <p>Please find below the setups for the day.<br>
            <body>''' + df.to_html() + '''</br></body>  
            <font color = "blue">
            <br>Thanks</br>
            </font> 
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <font color="black">
            Please note this is an automated mail<t1>
            </font>
       </p>
       </body>
       </style>
       </html>'''

     mailItem.Subject = "Setup report: " + " " + str(today.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))
     mailItem.To = 'varunadhawan@xyz.com'
     abhinit.Kumar@ihsmarkit.com'
     mailItem.HTMLBody = Body
     From = 'daviddhawan@xyz.com'
     mailItem.Send
```

Comment: Hey @Rahul, you have an Error on line 44: `abhinit.Kumar@ihsmarkit.com'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are just missing the empty brackets at the `Send()` method call on the last row.

```
 mailItem.Send()
```

Comment: He also has an Error on line 44. If you look at the syntax highlighting of this post it doesn't match up.